# Which macOS processes handle iMessage network communications?

Tags: macos, network, messages

I am trying to identify the macOS Catalina processes which handle network communication with Apple's iMessage servers.

If you have iMessage enabled and quit the Messages app, incoming messages are still delivered to your computer.

I've tried killing the `imagent` and `IMDPersistenceAgent` processes because they sounded related to messaging, but the former seems to be related to FaceTime only and killing the latter did not stop incoming iMessages.

To be clear: I am not simply trying to disable iMessage. I am trying to identify the processes that handle communication with iMessage. This is for two reasons:

1. The termination of these processes needs to be able to be executed in an automated bash script using `pkill` or something similar, and deactivation of iMessage cannot be done in such a way.
2. The computer needs to remain activated with the iMessage service so that when the processes are restarted (or the computer is restarted and the processes are launched on their own), any pending incoming iMessages are delivered. If iMessage were to be deactivated and then later activated, any messages during the period of time which it was deactivated would not be delivered.

Comment: will deactivate iMessage from your account in System Preference work for you?

Comment: @Udhy As I mentioned, disabling iMessage is not an option for me. I've added the two reasons to the original question.

Comment: Can’t you just turn on “Do not Disturb”

Comment: Unfortunately "Do not disturb" would not work for me because my goal is to stop network communication, not simply suppress/silence the notifications. In DND mode, the iMesages are still delivered and you can open the Messages app to view them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

iMessage message delivery is not as such handled seperately in a specific process for that single purpose.

Instead the generic `apsd` (Apple Push Notification Service Daemon) process handles the network communication. `apsd` handles Apple's push notification service in general.

The `imagent` process that you have already identified is indeed involved in iMessage, and not only Facetime. It is there to receive the notifications forwarded by the `apsd` process.

In addition there's a special case for iMessage attachments (i.e. very large iMessage messages in general). Their content is not transferred using push notificcations via `apsd`, but are rather downloaded from iCloud. That process is initiated via a notification from `apsd` however.

All in all this means that you can kill the `apsd` process, and keep it from restarting, and thereby stop iMessage messages from coming in (without "deactivating"). However it would also stop any other push notification from arriving at your computer.

Comment: And no way to control any of that I suppose?

Comment: What do you mean by "control"? - You have plenty of options for "control", just depends on what you mean by it.

Comment: Good point... I was wondering about the possibility of blocking iM notifications to my MacBook; i.e. only get them on my phone.

Comment: Why not simply not login to iMessage on your MacBook? Or if you just don't want the notifications themselves, then go to System Preferences > Notifications and set them to None for Messages.

Comment: That's (another) fair point. I guess it's because I find the (graphical) interface for notifications annoying. Silly I guess, but that's how I feel.

Comment: You do realise that this is something you have to do only once - right? - I.e. set notifications to none, and you'll never get a notification. It seems vastly more complicated to start closing down system processes to block messages.

Comment: @jksoegaard Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for, and I've accepted the answer. I was able to kill these processes using `sudo launchctl unload  /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.apsd.plist` and `launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.imagent.plist` after disabling [System Integrity Protection](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204899), but I'm not sure that I want to leave SIP disabled for this purpose. I may ask a separate question regarding alternative methods of accomplishing the same goals without having to unload `apsd` and `imagent`.

Comment: Why not just re-enable SIP after you've made the change?

Comment: My reason for asking this question was that I have a script I run about 3-5x/week when I'm on a train/plane/etc where I'm connecting to the Internet using either slow Wifi, cellular via phone hotspot, or VPN. The script kills off all non-essential apps/processes that would consume/compete for my limited bandwidth (in this case iMessage downloading attachments). When I'm back at home or in the office I reboot my computer to restart all the processes I need to be running normally. SIP would have to be disabled indefinitely in order to be able to kill off `apsd` automatically with the script.

Comment: Ah... you should really have asked this question instead of the question you've asked. A much easier way to achieve that you want is simply to block the network connectivity of apsd while you're on the train. Much simpler, doesn't require SIP changes.